# Creating a session in ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, session, .net-core

I am using the ASP.NET Core 3.1.
I need to set a session inside a action in a controller. I have Added the session in the ConfigureServices() method as:

```
services.AddSession(options => {
                options.IdleTimeout = System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3600);
            });
```

Also I have add code to use session in the Configure() method as:

```
app.UseSession();
```

In the controller class I am trying to create a session

```
HttpContext.Session.Set("sessionuser",xxx);
```

The xxx required is a byte[] unlike the string required in SetString() in .NET CORE 2.2
How to create the byte[] for this? Are there other better options in create sessions ?

Comment: What do you mean `How to create the byte[] for this` if you need string just use `HttpContext.Session.SetString()` and add reference to  `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`GetString`/`SetString` still exist in .NET Core 3.1. They're extensions (as they always have been) and live in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http` namespace. Perhaps you just need to add a `using`?

You haven't given a ton of info about your situation here, but it's possible you might be doing this from a class library. In which case, things become a bit trickier. ASP.NET Core 3.X moved to using a framework reference for the bulk of the ASP.NET Core code (instead of a package reference to the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` metapackage. However, that framework reference can only be utilized when targeting `netcoreapp3.0` or above. If you're targeting .NET Standard, you can only reference the old 2.X packages.

If you are only supporting ASP.NET Core 3.X apps, then you should simply change the class library's target to `netcoreapp3.1` and add the framework reference. If you need to also support ASP.NET Core 2.X apps, then you'll have to multi-target your class library to both `netcoreapp3.1` and `netstandard2.0`, and use conditionals in your project file to either add the framework reference or individual 2.X packages depending on the target. Andrew Lock has an excellent guide and more information at: https://andrewlock.net/converting-a-netstandard-2-library-to-netcore-3/

It's also worth mentioning that `System.Text.Json` supports serializing directly to/from `byte[]`. As such, if you're already using or intend to use generic type extensions for `ISession` to support types more complex than simple strings or value types that can be coerced to a string, then you can just rely on that instead:

```
public static class SessionExtensions
{
    public static void Set<T>(this ISession session, string key, T value)
    {
        session.Set(key, JsonSerializer.SerializeToUtf8Bytes(value));
    }

    public static T Get<T>(this ISession session, string key)
    {
        var value = session.Get(key);

        return value == null ? default(T) : 
            JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Note**:- If you are using Dotnet Core 2.0 or less then first of all install package from Nuget : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session

**Step1**: Add Session in ConfigureServices Method

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSession();
    }
```

**Step2**: Use Session in Configure Method

```
 app.UseSession();
```

**Step3**: add namespace in your controller class

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
```

**Step4**: Now SetString / GetString method would be available with HttpContext.Session

```
   public IActionResult Index()
    {
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("mysession", "mySessionValue");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this. Here I am saving a profile image:

```
HttpContext.Session.Set("Picture", Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(PictureBase64));
```

And for getting this:

```
if (Context.Session.TryGetValue("Picture", out byte[] pictureByteArr))
{
    picture = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(pictureByteArr);
}
```