# .NET Core 3.1 - storing temporary value between Controller calls

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

In an authorization scheme, I have 2 entry points in my angular frontend on the .NET side

at some point I need to store an identifier I generated

I tried with HttpContext.Items, but it gets discarded from one http call to another

- how can I store (and encrypt ?) that value ?

**the only codes I found online, encrypt one way, I need to decrypt it to reuse it**

```
// POST: api/requestAuthorization
[HttpPost]
[Route("requestAuthorization")]
public async Task<ActionResult<AuthorizeReturn>> RequestAuthorization(AuthorizeRequest authorizeRequest)
{
    string codeVerifier = GenerateCodeVerifier();

    httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Items["codeVerifier"] = codeVerifier;
           
    string url = ...

    AuthorizeReturn authorizeReturn = new AuthorizeReturn();
    authorizeReturn.Url = url;
    return authorizeReturn;
}
```

that code verifier needs to be used in a later entry point

```
// GET: api/EdenredConnect/authorize
[HttpGet]
[Route("authorize")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Authorize(...)
{
    string code_verifier = (string)httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Items["codeVerifier"];

    ...

    return Ok();
}
```

thanks for your help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a session in ASP.NET Core 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60493346/creating-a-session-in-asp-net-core-3-1)

Comment: You could put data in a header... encryption and decryption you need to implement yourself (note: put the encrypted bytes into base64 format.)

Comment: the issue is that since it's a third party that calls my controller, I cannot return a header, they wont send it back

Comment: Cookies /are/ HTTP Headers.... look under the headers for one named "Cookie".

Comment: If you need to share between controllers that would suggest a shared service where you store that value. Probably want to add that as scoped. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0#lifetime-and-registration-options

Comment: Does this third party that calls your controllers use `authorizeReturn.Url` value to make the second call? If so, you can just append your code there

Comment: I store now the encrypted value in a cookie, but anyone knows which aes is used by Aes aes = Aes.Create() ? 256 ? 512 ?

Answer (score 0):

From the controller just return codeVeryfier and on the front-end side just store it in seesion storage. Then if you are using axios you can use interceptors function that is called every request like this:

```cs
export const Axios = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'someURL',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
});

Axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    config.headers.CodeVeryfier = `${sessionStorage.getItem('codeVeryfier')}`;
    return config;
});
```

Then on the backend side you will be able to access codeVeryfier from HttpContext